# Using custom modules in PERL

Tags: perl, perl-module

I made myself a custom PERL module and it works when called by a script in the same directory, but not from outside the directory for somewhat obvious reasons. How do I use the module without installing it? eg:

```
use 5.012;
use warnings;
use Y:/my/dir/to/module.pm;
```

Comment: [`use lib 'Y:/my/dir';`](http://perldoc.perl.org/lib.html) `use to::module;`

Comment: You should use the `module-starter` program to build a template for an installable (CPAN style) module. That way you can install and test your module in a standard way, and maybe even post it to CPAN in the future. (more details here: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlnewmod.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
use lib 'Y:/my/dir/to';
use module; # BAD name for module, lowercase is reserved for pragmas...
```

Comment: Somehow add a link to `lib` and I will up-vote. One of [`perldoc lib`](http://perldoc.perl.org/lib.html) [p3rl.org/lib](http://p3rl.org/lib) [search.cpan.org/perldoc/lib](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/lib) or [metacpan.org/module/lib](http://metacpan.org/module/lib) would be fine.

Comment: Thanks for the grammar standard tip

Answer (score 0):

If you only have one module, instead of using lib, you can do this :

```
BEGIN {
  unshift @INC,"dir";
  #@INC is the directory list, where perl searches for .pm files
}

use Foo::Bar;  #dir/Foo/Bar.pm

#or 

do "dir/Foo/Bar.pm"; #perldoc -f do
```

Comment: While technically true, it's not really all that helpful. [lib](http://perldoc.perl.org/lib.html) was included in 5.001